# How to implement infinite scroll with multiple filter on data that get from Firebase in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, infinite-scroll

I'm using Firebase for my iOS application and I'm having trouble implement infinite scroll and filtering data together.

**What I need to do is:**

1. Display items with order/filter on multiple property (location, category, status . . .)
2. Implement infinite scroll when the user scrolled to bottom of the screen.

**I tried to think about some solutions:**

1. The first, I think that I'll query the data with the necessary conditions then limit the number of records by use `queryLimitedToFirst(N)`, and increase N when need to load the next items. But because Firebase can only filter on one property at a time and it's also a waste to reload data. So, I was thinking about the second solution.
2. As approaches are suggested from Frank van Puffelen ([Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)):

   > filter most on the server, do the rest on the client

   Yes, exactly like that. I'll execute `queryOrderedByKey`, `queryStartingAtValue`, `queryEndingAtValue` to implement infinite scroll, pull down the remaining data and filter that on client. But there is one problem that is I would not have enough items to display for the user if execute filter on the client.

   *For example: each time run the query, I receive 10 items. After data filtering process on the client, I just left 5 (can be 0) items meet the conditions to display to the user.*

   I don't want this because user may think there is a problem

**Can I please get some pointers on this? If I didn't structured the data properly, can I also get some tips there?**

Comment: You've seen what is considered the default answer for this problem. Unless you've tried something and are having trouble to make this work (in which case: post what you've tried) this question is either a duplicate or off-topic.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I was looking for some answer. But most of them is to solve the problem either "Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase" or "Infinite scroll in Firebase". No, I don't solve two separate problems, I want to ask how to solve the problem when doing these two things together.